# JavaScript - Filling multiple Form PDFs in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-generation

I want to create a script that would receive multiple objects of data to be filled in a PDF, I've managed to make it work for a single file, but when I try to create multiple files with the help of a for loop only the last file gets filled correctly, the other ones get created but are empty files.

The script is inside a simple HTML display to start the functionality:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fill PDF with JavaScript</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf-lib/1.16.0/pdf-lib.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="fillPDF">Rellenar PDF</button>
    <script>
        // function to fill the fields of a PDF
        async function fillPDF(namePDF, dataPDF) {
            const existingPdfBytes = await fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy/?quest=https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/dod_character.pdf').then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());

            // Create a PDF from existing bytes
            const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);
            const form = pdfDoc.getForm();

            // Fill the fields
            form.getTextField('CharacterName 2').setText(dataPDF.name);
            form.getTextField('Age').setText(dataPDF.number);
            form.getTextField('Allies').setText(dataPDF.phoneNum);
            
            form.flatten()

            // Create a new PDF from the filled data
            const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

            const pickerOpts = {
                types: [
                {
                    description: "PDF Document (.pdf)",
                    accept: {
                    "application/*": [".pdf"],
                    },
                },
                ],
                excludeAcceptAllOption: true,
                multiple: false,
            };

            const fileHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker(pickerOpts);
            const fileStream = await fileHandle.createWritable();
            

            // Save the file
            const blob = new Blob([pdfBytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            await fileStream.write(blob);
            await fileStream.close();
            
        }
        // objects of data to fill
        const pdf1 = {
            "number": "1",
            "name": "John",
            "phoneNum": "4865138186",
        }

        const pdf2 = {
            "number": "2",
            "name": "Jane",
            "phoneNum": "51675469819",
        }
        //array that contains the objects
        const PDFs = [
            ["pdf-form",pdf1],
            ["pdf-form",pdf2]
        ]
        // function that starts the process
        async function processPDF(){
            PDFs.forEach(async (element) =>{
                
                await fillPDF(element[0],element[1])
            })
            
        }
        // start function with button press
        document.getElementById('fillPDF').addEventListener('click', processPDF);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What it does now is when the function in executed multiple Save File windows are opened, and just the file saved on the last opened window is correctly created.

I need the created files to have different names, thats why I'm using the Save File window, but if there is another alternative you might know for this kind of problem please let me know, any advise is appreciated

Comment: Your `PDFs` array has the same `namePDF` value in both subarrays. You are writing to the same PDF multiple times.

Comment: When the function ends a new file is created from the original 'pdf-form.pdf' but the original is not affected in any way, does filling the same file really affects here?

Comment: I just tried making a copy from the original `pdf-form.pdf` with a different name and gave it as a parameter for the 2nd object of data to be filled but the result was the same, just the last file is created correctly

Comment: My next guess would be that the loop iterations all running concurrently are somehow confusing things. `forEach` doesn't respect asynchronous functions passed as its parameter; it will fire all of them in succession without waiting for them to complete. Try replacing it with an actual `for` loop and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I changed it to a `for` loop and it waited to open the 2nd Save File window, but now only the first file is being filled correclty and the 2nd is empty, I will look if there is a problem with the `arrayBuffer` or `Blob` data from the original file, thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: @KJ I've donde the edits so now everyone can try it, I made tests and both files are being filled correctly, I'm gonna have to chech if the problem is my file or something else, thanks for the insight though